# Drupal6: Linebreaks from fckeditor aren't reflected on page

Tags: drupal-6, wysiwyg, themes, rich-text-editor

I think this might be a problem with the theme I'm using ([Nitobe](http://drupal.org/project/nitobe)). I'm also using the WYSIWYG rich text editor [fckeditor](http://drupal.org/project/fckeditor).

When I make formatting changes to a post using fckeditor, such as bolding, italicizing, or more substantial changes, like adding a numbered list, it works fine. However, when I try to add line breaks, the changes are not reflected in the published version. I look at the html, and there's no `<p>` or `<br />` tags there whatsover.

So, I might have some text that I edit like this in the editor:

"blah blah blah

foo foo foo"

When I save and view the node, it looks like this:

"blah blah blah 
foo foo foo"

Then I go back to edit it again, and it looks like this:

"blah blah blah

foo foo foo"

Could it be that Nitobe and fckeditor are incompatible?

Comment: @Rosarch: You often use the 'drupal6' tag, which is not used anymore in favor of 'drupal-6'. I adjusted it on all your questions, but you might want to look for that in future questions, as they will get more attention that way. (Many people look for new questions only within specific tags, so using a seldom used tag lowers the visibility of your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: use an input filter without the line break converter.